# How to does Regexp Ruby to match with "!=" exacly and dont only with =

Tags: regex, ruby

I have been to do a ruby regexp path to find != , < and > together and I got it, but if only find ! or = symbol match too with my path /[!=<>]/.

How can I to does a group for it?

Thank lot.

Comment: Can you edit to give a few examples of strings that do and do not match, and for the ones that don't match explain why they don't match?

Comment: Hi @Cary Swoveland, in my case if I had a string "dsed=dfd!".match(/[!=<>]/) that find it, but only I needed that only find it, if "!=" were in this path, add < and >  dont worry if find it alone, that is well. In other way if I have a "dsed=dfd!".match(/!=|<|>/) dont find it, because only math if find "!=" or ">" or "<". Exactly like give us next answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `/!=|<|>/`?

You could even use [Regexp.union](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union)

```
Regexp.union(/!=/, /</, /</)
```